# How can I assign a specific profile in dependent Maven module?

Tags: maven, module, profile

My project has a structure like this:

```
-parent
--common
--dao
--server
--webserver
```

The module `dao` has multi-profiles and `webserver` is dependent on all other modules. How can i assign which profile in `dao` will be used when packaging `webserver`?

The module `dao` contains different jdbc connections and i need to package different profile for different environment. I thought put jdbc connections in `dao` would be appropriate.

Comment: very likely it is an [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Why are you having different profile in dao module, and why you want your `webserver` to depends on a specific `profile` of dao?  In short, what you are asking is something not achievable, but depends on your need, there are other way to solve it.

Comment: First why do you need a profile in dao module?

Comment: That sounds wrong. You should have a configuration in your webserver module which results in different webserver package according to the appropriate environment. So in result you would get a war file for environment 1 a war file for environment 2 etc. This can be handles for example with this: https://github.com/khmarbaise/multienv-maven-plugin

Comment: So I just can't set profiles in `dao`? I know apache maven-war-plugin, it's similar with multienv-maven-plugin, I believe.

Comment: I personally will avoid building different artifacts for different environments.  You should have the same WAR deployable to different environments, with external config file / env property etc

Comment: `I thought put jdbc connections in dao would be appropriate`: It is not.

Comment: Thank you guys. I will try to refactor my project while it's not a big thing to do.